# WebSql not working for this form with inputs

Tags: html

I am not sure why WebSql does not work for this html code. I want to have the values of the input be saved into WebSql, when save is clicked on, page needs to be refreshed for the data to be stored in the database. But it is not working as I wanted to

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Open DataBase</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var Database_Name = 'MyDatabase';
        var Version = 1.0;
        var Text_Description = 'My First Web-SQL Example';
        var Database_Size = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        var dbObj = openDatabase(Database_Name, Version, Text_Description, Database_Size);
        dbObj.transaction(function (tx) {

            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee_Table (id unique, Name, Location,did)');
        function Insert() {

                var id = document.getElementById("tbID").value;
                var name = document.getElementById("tbName").value;
                var location = document.getElementById("tbLocation").value;
                var did = document.getElementById("tbLdept").value;
                dbObj.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('insert into Employee_Table(id, Name, Location,did) values(' + id + ',"' + name + '","' + location + '",' + did + ')');
                  });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="hh"></p>
    <form id="frm1">
        <table id="tblinsert">
            <tr>
                <td>ID:</td>
                <td id="tdorginal"><input type="text" id="tbID" /><span style="color:red">*ID must be unique</span></td>
                <td id="tdid" style="display:none">
                    <select id="ddlid" onchange="myFunction()"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="rowName">
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="tbName" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="rowLocation">
                <td>Location:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="tbLocation" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="rowdept">
                <td>Dept:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="tbLdept"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <br />
    <button id="btnInsert" onclick="Insert()" style="color:green;display:block">Save</button>
```

Comment: The `Insert` method is defined within the transaction so has a different scope to the button that is trying to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the `click` handler within the initial transaction all should be OK as the scope in which the `Insert` function is defined is now the same. I modified the SQL to add quotes around the Department (`did`) as I figured that would be text - though this is not necessarily true. I tested the following and it works OK.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(e)=>{
            
                var Database_Name = 'MyDatabase';
                var Version = 1.0;
                var Text_Description = 'My First Web-SQL Example';
                var Database_Size = 2 * 1024 * 1024;

                var dbo = openDatabase( Database_Name, Version, Text_Description, Database_Size );

                dbo.transaction(function(tx){

                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee_Table ( id unique, Name, Location, did )');
                    
                    function Insert(){
                        var id = document.getElementById("tbID").value;
                        var name = document.getElementById("tbName").value;
                        var location = document.getElementById("tbLocation").value;
                        var did = document.getElementById("tbLdept").value;
                        
                        dbo.transaction(function(tx){
                            tx.executeSql('insert into Employee_Table( id, Name, Location, did ) values(' + id + ',"' + name + '","' + location + '","' + did + '")');
                        });
                    };
                    
                    document.querySelector('button[data-name="save"]').addEventListener('click',Insert)
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <p id="hh"></p>
        
        <form id="frm1">
            <table id="tblinsert">
                <tr>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td id="tdorginal">
                        <input type="text" id="tbID" value=23 />
                        <span style="color:red">*ID must be unique</span>
                    </td>
                    <td id="tdid" style="display:none">
                        <select id="ddlid" onchange="myFunction()"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="rowName">
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="tbName" value='Terl 14' /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr id="rowLocation">
                    <td>Location:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="tbLocation" value='Planet Zarg' /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="rowdept">
                    <td>Dept:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="tbLdept" value='Asteroid Collision Counter' /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        
        <br />
        
        <button data-name='save' style="color:green;display:block">Save</button>
    </body>
</html>
```